# Using a different domain in Url.Action in asp mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am making an ajax call to a remote api in my web application.

I am using the `Url.Action("actionName", "controller")`. But the issue is that its taking the current url of my web application.

I have a different domain for my remote web api. I have tried to used `Url.Action("actionName", "controller", host)` where `host` represents the domain of the web api. But it generates both url of the web application and the remote api.

How can I explicitly specify the url of my domain for the remote web api ?

Please help.

Comment: You can assign URL as the string instead of Url.action.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use the remote url directly, `Url.Action` would use your current domain, so in your case you would have to do something like

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST" //Doesnt have to be a post, depends on your endpoint,
   url: //your remote url,
   data: //some data if needed to pass to endpoint,
   success: function (response) {
}
});
```

Comment: What if I don't want to use the url directly ?
How I can specify a custom route to use my web api domain ?

Comment: Unfortunately thats not possible, the only route to your web api domain is through the URL for it in the way stated above, it would be nice if that were possible